# Nested class public method takes parent class as input

Tags: c++, c++11, nested, pybind11

I found this in a 3rd party codebase

```
class Foo {
 public:
  class Log {
   public:
   static Log method(Foo& foo);
  };
};
```

I'm omitting many other methods from both classes for conciseness. It compiles, but it is giving me a hard time when trying to create python bindings around it via pybind11. Is this an acceptable practice or should I simply refactor the class to extract this Log class out of it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common practice if the Log class needs access to the data of Foo class. But it is also totally acceptable to write the Log class as other or friend class. In case of independent class you may need the appropriate getters for the Log class.